# VSTO Excel Add-In not getting loaded for all users (using the every one option installation) in a windows 7 office 2007 32 bit machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto

I have a VSTO add-in created using VS2010. I am developing the VSTO application using a 32 bit windows XP machine. I have created a 32 bit VS installer to deploy this add-in for all 32 bit office excel applications. The add-in works fine in all environments when i perform the installation on per user basis. The add-in loads  in 32 bit excel 2010 on windows 7 for the every one option(all users). But the excel add-in failed to load for the all users option in a 32 bit office 2007 machine in windows 7. The registry entires on 2007 machine getting created under the HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins. But when excel loads the add-in is not getting loaded by default. The excel add-in is showing up in the disable items list. Even try to select the add-in from the list, then also the add-in not getting loaded.

If anyone can provide support which will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how to do it with VS installer, but for current users the addins entry will be created here

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\Addins
```

and for all users on that machine will be created here

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\Addins
```

More information is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386106.aspx)